# Effect of changing $n$ to $n-ik$ in an electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose you have a plane electromagnetic wave that crosses a medium with index of refraction $n$ with equation:$$e^{i\omega(t-\frac{nx}{c})}$$
Where $c$ is the speed of light.

What's the effect of changing $n$ by $n-ik$,$i=\sqrt{-1}$.

What does k physically represents?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Did you search ["Complex index of refraction"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Complex_refractive_index)?

Comment: No, I found this exercise when self-studying electromagnetism. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252883/em-relative-permittivity/252901#252901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do some manipulation:

$$\begin{align}
E &\propto e^{i\omega(t - nx/c)}\\
&\propto e^{i\omega(t + ikx/c - nx/c)}\\
&\propto e^{-\omega kx/c}e^{i\omega(t - nx/c)}
\end{align}$$

so, you see an exponential decay in the electric field as the wave travels a distance x.  Therefore, one can interpret $\omega k$ as giving you information about how much of the field the medium is absorbing.